# Apache error - mod_fcgid: too many processes, skip the spawn request- Hangs Server

Tags: apache, fastcgi, dreamhost

We are running a LAMP stack on a Dreamhost dedicated server. Since updating to PHP 5.6 FastCGI we have been getting more frequent server outages and slow response times even with nominal server load. Apache is throwing the following error:

```
[Tue Jul 14 14:58:09 2015] [error] mod_fcgid: domain=<domain>.com too many /dh/cgi-system/php56.cgi processes (current:20, max:20), skip the spawn request
```

I have [read of some FastCGI configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540180/mod-fcgid-php-apache-lockup) that might help, but Dreamhost did not suggest modifying these settings. Would it be safe to update these settings on a Dreamhost server and would this help?

We are planning an audit of all CURL requests to add timeouts. Will this help the issue? Is there something else we can do to stop the php spawn requests from being skipped? Is there a way to identify an offending script that might be hanging the server?